# Local drupal cURL requests results in "forbidden" error

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I can make the following request from any remote client/server:

```
curl 'http://my.drupalserver.com/node/4688?_format=json' -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/hal+json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

And it works: I get my node as expected.

However: when I make this **exact same request** from the same server the website is hosted on I get a **403 forbidden** error.

I'm at my wits end, the drupal web profiler for both requests clearly shows the request headers are identical, so I have no idea what the problem could be.

I have already cleared the caches, checked the "trusted hosting", ...

I'm running Drupal 8.0.5

Comment: Where is the request being denied? Can you check the Apache/Nginx logs? Perhaps they will have further information.

Comment: Did you try to add into hosts on local just for testing  ? 
127.0.0.1 my.drupalserver.com